# como puedo cambia la ruta en la que se ejecuta mi terminal de visual studio code como administrador?

Tags: vscode

soy principiante en programacion y la intentar ejecutar mi terminal de visual studio code me apare una ruta predeterminada en la cual no me sirve trabajar, me gustaria saber como poder cambiar esta ruta o que puedo hacer.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [SO.es] aquí se suelen hacer preguntas relacionadas con la programación. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y veas [ask] para que entiendas como funciona el sitio. Lo que estás pidiendo, no es más que cambiar de ruta como lo harías en una consola normal. `cd ruta`. La ruta puede ser tanto recursiva como absoluta. También puedes utilizar `cd ..` para ir un nivel atras

Answer (score 1):

En VSC siempre te va a mostrar la ruta donde se encuentra tu proyecto.
Tienes 2 opciones:

1. tener la carpeta de tu proyecto donde quieres tener la ruta que te "sirve".
2. abrir una Terminal:

- Abrir Configuración, mediante el menú o presionando Ctrl + ,
- En la sección de Perfiles, selecciona el que quieres establecer un directorio de inicio

Comment: Me entró la curiosidad y encontré que sí hay una opción:
1. Abrir Configuración en VSC, mediante el menú o presionando Ctrl + ,
2. En el campo 'Buscar configuración', escribe cwd
3. Escribir la ruta en el campo de la sección Terminal > Integrated: Cwd

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo e utilizado y me funciono perfecto bien.